# System.QueryException: only aggregate expressions use field aliasing in package?

Tags: managed-package

Hi I am using Round Robin force rule package in my project starting it was working fine from last week i am getting error.

```
message": "RunAssignmentRulesOnLead: execution of AfterInsert\n\ncaused by: System.QueryException: only aggregate expressions use field aliasing\n\n(forcerules)\nTrigger.RunAssignmentRulesOnLead: line 2, column 1",
```

Already i have force rules in my system still getting issue

Debug Logs

[image]

Package classes cannot view to check error also.

Can anyone help me sort out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this an open source package or an ISV one? If the latter, you should contact the vendor. Note that I would assume this relates to some configuration where you are able to define some SOQL query snippet and this incorrectly includes an alias, or has a missing comma between field names.

Comment: The missing comma between field names is the likely culprit. Perhaps the package has you define the SOQL expression in either a CMDT, Custom Setting, or custom object and you just missed the comma